# DataTable / DataGridView Data Filter

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I need to filter a data bound DataGridView when a CheckBox is checked/unchecked.

The filter is based on Completed/Uncompleted Records.

When I load the data into the underlying DataTable, I select all records from the Table.

When the application runs I want it to start up with only uncompleted records present.

When the user checks the check box it switches to completed tasks.

I have been able to do this with using DataView.RowFilter(), but the problem is that when ever a user marks an item as completed within the grid, it automatically removes it from view. (where the CheckBox is unchecked).

I only want the Data to filter as and when the CheckBox is checked/unchecked.

The one thing that I want to stay away from is re-loading the data from the database each time the CheckBox.checked event is fired, with a specific SQL statement.

I want to filter the Data in memory, but only as and when The user interacts with the CheckBox.

Any Suggestions welcome.

Comment: could you share your codes?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`DataTable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx) to filter the data instead of `DataView.RowFilter` and only update the Select filter when the checkbox check status changes.

Comment: This returns an array of DataRows?

Comment: @Derek you could use the DataRows returned by this as the datasource for the DataGridView

Comment: The Datasource for my Datagrid is A binding Source, Should I set the Datasource for the Binding Source as the returned DataRows?

Comment: @Derek that should work. As you're using a BindingSource, you have another option - the [BindingSource.Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter.aspx) property

Comment: I'll look at using the BindingSource Filter, I need to save changes back in the grid to Database, thanks.

Comment: The Binding Source filter is fine, but again I have a problem where by the Items that the user change from complete in the grid makes them instantly disappear from view. I want to have a the grid filtered, but not set as a default view until told otherwise. I'm not sure its possible without having to make calls back to the database.